# Borders with different widths

Tags: mdframed, border

I'm looking for a way to draw a border on the top and left, but they should have different widths. I've been trying to do this using the [mdframed](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to draw a border on the left that has a different width from the border at the top.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[rightline=false,bottomline=false]{topbot}

\begin{document}

\begin{topbot}
\subsection*{This is the title}
\end{topbot}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

This is what I have:

[image: Border with wrong width]

And this is what I am looking for:

[image: right border]

Comment: Do you want to get text boxes with this format? or Do you want to get section and subsection titles with this format?

Comment: @Ignasi: I am after text boxes. See my updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I think this is not the way to change `section` format, here you have a solution for OP's example with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{leftrule=5pt, toprule=.5pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, colback=white, notitle, sharp corners, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{topbot}
\subsection*{This is the title}
\end{topbot}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

If a fancy format for unnumbered sections is what is desired. `titlesec` provides  better solutions than a `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` environment containing a subsection command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{name=\subsection, numberless}
  {\titlerule\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1mm}{\strut}}}
  {.5em}{#1}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{This is the title}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there are two issues... I don't need this to be section-specific so I ran your first MWE but a) the color is a light grey, not black, without this being specified, and b) there is a box AROUND the whole block (so also at the bottom and right hand side). I will show a screenshot in my post, as I don't know how to add it in a comment.

Comment: Actually, let me post a new question so this stays on topic and the whole thing doesn't get too complicated. I'll accept this answer and post a separate question for my second inquiry. Thanks!